# Grouping Python tuple list

Tags: grouping, python

I have a list of (label, count) tuples like this:

```
[('grape', 100), ('grape', 3), ('apple', 15), ('apple', 10), ('apple', 4), ('banana', 3)]
```

From that I want to sum all values with the same label (same labels always adjacent) and return a list in the same label order:

```
[('grape', 103), ('apple', 29), ('banana', 3)]
```

I know I could solve it with something like:

```
def group(l):
    result = []
    if l:
        this_label = l[0][0]
        this_count = 0
        for label, count in l:
            if label != this_label:
                result.append((this_label, this_count))
                this_label = label
                this_count = 0
            this_count += count
        result.append((this_label, this_count))
    return result
```

But is there a more Pythonic / elegant / efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can do what you want:

```
import itertools
import operator

L = [('grape', 100), ('grape', 3), ('apple', 15), ('apple', 10),
     ('apple', 4), ('banana', 3)]

def accumulate(l):
    it = itertools.groupby(l, operator.itemgetter(0))
    for key, subiter in it:
       yield key, sum(item[1] for item in subiter) 

print(list(accumulate(L)))
# [('grape', 103), ('apple', 29), ('banana', 3)]
```

Comment: I like the use of `operator.itemgetter` in place of `lambda`.

Comment: This requires the list to be sorted on the first key. If it isn't already sorted, then the defaultdict approach from ghostdog74 is a much better solution.

Comment: Why would you use `operator` instead of `lambda`?

Answer (score 8):

using itertools and list comprehensions

```
import itertools

[(key, sum(num for _, num in value))
    for key, value in itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: x[0])]
```

**Edit:** as gnibbler pointed out: if `l` isn't already sorted replace it with `sorted(l)`.

Comment: to use groupby you must first ensure that the sequence is pregrouped (all the 'grape' adjacent, etc). one way to do that is to sort the sequence first

Comment: @Thomas Wouters, yes you are correct ("same labels are always adjacent")

Answer (score 6):

```
import collections
d=collections.defaultdict(int)
a=[]
alist=[('grape', 100), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 10), ('apple', 4), ('grape', 3), ('apple', 15)]
for fruit,number in alist:
    if not fruit in a: a.append(fruit)
    d[fruit]+=number
for f in a:
    print (f,d[f])
```

output

```
$ ./python.py
('grape', 103)
('banana', 3)
('apple', 29)
```

Comment: This does search in `alist` for each item which makes your algorithm `O(n^2)` not a good thing.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> L=[('grape', 100), ('grape', 3), ('apple', 15), ('apple', 10), ('apple', 4), ('banana', 3)]
>>> [(x,sum(map(itemgetter(1),y))) for x,y in groupby(L, itemgetter(0))]
[('grape', 103), ('apple', 29), ('banana', 3)]
```

Answer (score 4):

my version without itertools 
`[(k, sum([y for (x,y) in l if x == k])) for k in dict(l).keys()]`

Answer (score 1):

Method

```
def group_by(my_list):
    result = {}
    for k, v in my_list:
        result[k] = v if k not in result else result[k] + v
    return result
```

Usage

```
my_list = [
    ('grape', 100), ('grape', 3), ('apple', 15),
    ('apple', 10), ('apple', 4), ('banana', 3)
]

group_by(my_list) 

# Output: {'grape': 103, 'apple': 29, 'banana': 3}
```

You Convert to List of tuples like `list(group_by(my_list).items())`.

Answer (score 0):

Or a simpler more readable answer ( without itertools ):

```
pairs = [('foo',1),('bar',2),('foo',2),('bar',3)]

def sum_pairs(pairs):
  sums = {}
  for pair in pairs:
    sums.setdefault(pair[0], 0)
    sums[pair[0]] += pair[1]
  return sums.items()

print sum_pairs(pairs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler answer without any third-party libraries:

```
dct={}

for key,value in alist:
    if key not in dct:
        dct[key]=value
    else:
        dct[key]+=value
```

Comment: I don't see any third-party libraries here. [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html), [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html), and [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) are all part of the standard library. They come with Python.