# Grouping the same name in lists in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am new to python, so would like your help on the matter. I have a list of tuples. I want to group these lists on the basis of the first element of the list, which may repeat. Also, I would like to sum the 2nd and 3rd element of the list for repeating elements.

Sample Input:

```
[("henry", 10, 20), ("alex", 25, 40), ("henry", 13, 21)]
```

Sample output:

```
[("henry", 23, 41), ("alex", 25, 40)]
```

I have tried the groupby method in python, but it works only on sorted lists.

Comment: You need to use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). A similar kind of problem is already addressed and solved using `itertools.groupby` in this StackOverflow question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249036/grouping-python-tuple-list Please make sure to look for existing questions that might be similar before posting a duplicate.

Comment: @Md.AbdulMunim: `groupby` requires the input to be sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC here is a solution using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
lst = [['henry', 10, 20], ['henry', 23, 42], ['alex', 25, 40]]
import pandas as pd
#Create a dataframe using the list
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
#Name the columns
df.columns = ['name', 'val1', 'val2']
#Groupby name and sum it.
df.groupby('name').sum()
#Will produce this result
       val1  val2
name
alex     25    40
henry    33    62

#To access the rows and columns following is the example
dfg = df.groupby('name').sum()
#Row, Column
dfg.iloc[0][0]
#Will get 25 & likewise can get any other values
25 
#Another way to get
dfg.loc["alex"][0]
#Will get 25 & likewise can get any other values
25
```

Comment: Hi Abbas, can you tell me how can I access a particular row and column from this table? forexample if I need the value 25, how do I get it?

Comment: Added example how to access row and column.