# Python sum of second and third element of tuple in list of tuples grouped by first

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you get the sum of second and third values in a list of tuples grouped by the first value?

I.e:

`list_of_tuples = [(1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 4), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0)]`

`expected_output = [(1, 5, 5), (2, 3, 0)]`

I found several [great answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249036/grouping-python-tuple-list) on StackOverflow doing this found tuples with two values, but couldn't figure out how to adjust them for summing both second and third values.

One of the good answers for just the second value was this:

```
def sum_pairs(pairs):
sums = {}
for pair in pairs:
    sums.setdefault(pair[0], 0)
    sums[pair[0]] += pair[1]
return sums.items()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do it like this:

```
list_of_tuples = [(1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 4), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0)]

# create empty dictionary to store data
sums = {}

# iterate over list of typles
for pair in list_of_tuples:

  # create new item in dictionary if it didnt exist
  if pair[0] not in sums: sums[pair[0]] = [pair[0], 0 ,0]

  # sum the values
  sums[pair[0]][1] += pair[1]
  sums[pair[0]][2] += pair[2]

#print resulting tuple   
print(tuple(sums.values()))
```

Comment: No guarantee that the initial ordering will be preserved (at least in Python < 3.6)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group based on the first item, and then take the cumulative sums of all the last two items in each group:

```
from itertools import groupby

list_of_tuples = [(1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 4), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0)]
lst = [(k,)+tuple(sum(x) for x in zip(*g))[1:] 
                         for k, g in groupby(list_of_tuples, lambda x: x[0])]
print(lst)
# [(1, 5, 5), (2, 3, 0)]
```

Comment: Note, the tuples need to be grouped already by the first element, so you'd have to sort first, for example, unless you can make that assumption.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No assumptions: *in a list of tuples grouped by the first value*

Comment: Aha! Missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `defaultdict` as a grouper:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> grouper = defaultdict(lambda: (0,0))
>>> list_of_tuples = [(1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 4), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0)]
>>> for a, b, c in list_of_tuples:
...     x, y = grouper[a]
...     grouper[a] = (x + b, y + c)
...
>>> grouper
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x102b240d0>, {1: (5, 5), 2: (3, 0)})
```

Now, you can always get a list of tuples back like this:

```
>>> [(k, a, b) for k, (a, b) in grouper.items()]
[(1, 5, 5), (2, 3, 0)]
```